# Permission at the server scope can only be granted when the current database is master

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, tfs

While configuring TFS on adding database I am getting below error.

> Permission at the server scope can only be granted  when the current database is master

[image]

Comment: Please use screenshot and not a camera.

Answer (score 0):

> Permissions at the server scope can only be granted when the current
>   database is master

This message occurs when the Server scope permissions are tried to be modified from any other database other than master.

The workaround is to set the default database for the running user's SQL Login to be 'master'. The running user here means the one you are trying to create Team Project Collection.

Take a look at this similar issue [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wlennon/2013/06/03/tfs-2012-scheduled-backups-wizard-fails-with-permissions-at-the-server-scope-can-only-be-granted-when-the-current-database-is-master/).

Answer (score 0):

Further explanation of the workaround Patrick mentioned, the SQL Login that should be set as the default 'master' is the login performing the install. On our 2 server implementation where the data tier is on a separate server the install application creates a login used by the application tier - that is not the one needing the default.